# Debug .NET apps on Raspberry Pi - dotnet has exited with code 0

Tags: .net, azure, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-hub, vscode-remote

I have a question regarding debugging in VS Code. I have created simple console app. I deployed the solution to a Raspberry PI, connected via SSH, and ran the app.  It worked.

I would like to use the debugger with this solution.  I tried to configure launch.json as specified here: [Debug .NET apps on Raspberry Pi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/debugging?tabs=framework-dependent&pivots=vscode) but I get an error message:

> "Loaded '/home/myuser/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.0/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. The program '[5362] dotnet' has exited with
> code 0 (0x0)."

I have installed dotnet and as I said it works when I run it manually once I am connected via SSH.

This is my configuration from lanuch.json (I changed username and host)

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Remote Launch - Framework-dependent",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "~/.dotnet/dotnet",
      "args": ["~//dev/iot/soil-moisture/SoilMoisture.dll"],
      "cwd": "~/dev/iot/soil-moisture/",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "pipeProgram": "ssh",
        "pipeArgs": ["username@host"],
        "debuggerPath": "~/vsdbg/vsdbg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or what to try next?

Comment: hi im encountering the same problem at the moment, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't resolve the issue. I tried with a self-contained package but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the doc you linked. I found this question while I was looking for a solution for that same problem, so I reckon you're not alone.

I'm trying to figure out why it's not working, and I think I've tracked down the person to talk to. In the meantime, I've isolated the issue to .NET 7 apps on `linux-arm`.

I'll update the doc in a day or two when I figure out why it's broken. So your possible workarounds (for the moment) are any one of the following:

- Run Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit
- Target .NET 6.0

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your input. I target .NET 6.0 and it works. If there is anything that I can help you with .NET 7, please let me know!

Answer (score -1):

There are couple of ways we can deploy the .Net application onto Raspberry Pi.

1. [Deploying a framework-dependent application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment#deploying-a-framework-dependent-app)
2. [Deploying a self-contained application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment#deploying-a-self-contained-app)

I just want to point that the Blink Led tutorial advises to deploy the project as Self-contained application. If you have followed the same deployment process, make sure you have selected the launch.json template for self-contained process. Please find the below image for reference.

[image]

The template format varies based on the deployment process and make sure you have used the appropriate one on Visual Studio Code per your needs.

**Note:** The launch.json file is only needed if you plan to use Visual Studio Code. If you decide to [Debug the application on Raspberry Pi using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/debugging?tabs=self-contained&pivots=visualstudio), you will not need launch.json file. You can debug the app just by installing .Net Run-time on Raspberry Pi and deploy the app again with few configuration changes to start debugging.

You can download the .Net runtime for Raspberry Pi from the following [URL](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0). Please refer the below image to find the distribution I have tested with.

[image]

Once you download the distribution, follow the steps in the following [article](https://elbruno.com/2019/12/30/raspberypi-how-to-install-net-core-3-1-in-a-raspberry-pi-4/) to set up and install .Net run time. Once you have successfully installed it, you can verify the version by running `dotnet --info` on the Raspberry Pi. Here is what the command should return.

[image]

Once .Net run-time is installed, you can set up your solution using the steps [prepare-your-application-for-debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022#prepare-your-application-for-debugging) to ***build and deploy the application again on to the Raspberry Pi with the configuration changes made*** (I have deployed the app using the [Self-contained app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment#deploying-a-self-contained-app) approach)

After the application is deployed, you can run the application on your Raspberry Pi and debug it in your local machine by following the steps outline here -- [Attach the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022#attach-the-debugger)

Find the following images for the configurations I made

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice the break point being hit on the Visual Studio after attaching the process.
[image]